# on keydown execute function and and pause the execution of the next function JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

For now I have that when key is down it changes colours, and as soon as it is up it changes back. But this is really quick and kinda causes migraine effect.

I want to do so when the key is pressed it would keep the changes for a second or two and then changes back to original colours without pausing any other function that is not inside these ones.

```js
$(window).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 32) {
      $('body').css('background', '#26A65B');
      $('#word').css('color', '#415A77');
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
      $('body').css('background', '#D64541');
      $('#word').css('color', '#415A77');
    }
  });
$(window).on ('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 37) {
      $('body').css('background', '#415A77');
      $('#word').css('color', '#ed7d3a');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: To execute some code after some period of time, you can use `setTimeout`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: or you can use library for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323474/jquery-how-to-fade-in-out-from-one-color-to-another-possible-3rd-party-plugi

Comment: @LaurynasStoma you can include JQuery on the left hand side if you're inserting a snippet.

Comment: This feels like jQuery color animation which has a number of questions and answers.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863640/jquery-animate-and-backgroundcolor  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461984/jquery-animate-not-working-with-colors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Answer (score 0):

Something among this lines should help you. You have to put some flag variable as helper, because only `setTimeout` would not help you,, cause each new keydown would just break setTimeout and then increase chances of migraine effects :)

Test it with left and right arrow keys:

```js
$('body').focus();
var flag = false;
$(window).on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (flag) return;
    if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 32) {
      $('body').css('background', '#26A65B');
      $('#word').css('color', '#415A77');
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
      $('body').css('background', '#D64541');
      $('#word').css('color', '#415A77');
    }
  });
$(window).on ('keyup', function (e) {
    if( flag ) return;
    if( ! flag ) flag = true;
    setTimeout( function(){
      flag = false;
      if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 37) {
        $('body').css('background', '#415A77');
        $('#word').css('color', '#ed7d3a');
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`timeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) on each keyup. If there's already a timeout running, [clear it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout) and set another.

```js
let timeout = null;
$(window).on('keydown',(e => {
  if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 32) {
    $('body').css('background', '#26A65B');
    $('#word').css('color', '#415A77');
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    $('body').css('background', '#D64541');
    $('#word').css('color', '#415A77');
  }
}));
$(window).on('keyup',(e => {
  if (e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 37) {
    if (timeout !== null) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      $('body').css('background', '#415A77');
      $('#word').css('color', '#ed7d3a');
    }, 2000);
  }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="word">Hello</div>
```